# Error:2 File Not Found - Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows, service

I just built a simple Windows Service and am having trouble getting it to start

```
The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.

M:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug>Net start WindowsService1.exe
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The code is on a mapped network drive and I have the Service Account set as

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
```

Is this some sort of permissions problem? Is there any tool or utility to diagnose this kind of problem?

Update: The code is just an empty service

```
namespace WindowsService1
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
}
```

Update 2: The error is when I start the service, not when I install it. I'm running the following command successfully

```
M:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug>installutil WindowsService1.exe
```

Comment: this may be a permissions problem or not, but without the code it is hard to say.

Comment: You need to install (register) the service first (see help for sc.exe, the command line program that allows you to interact with the Service Controller), and then use `net start` and `net stop` to control it (or use `sc start` and `sc stop`). Most services also accept an `/install` command line switch that does the registration with Windows for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code is on a mapped network drive and I have the Service Account set as:
>
> ```
> this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
> ```

That sounds like the problem. The LOCALSERVICE account does not have rights to see the network drive. At the very least the process needs to be able to see its executable file. Quite what the failure mechanism is, I'm not sure, but surely this is the root cause.

Put the files onto a local drive, and try again.

Comment: Thanks David, I have a feeling you are correct. However the local drives on our computers are locked down and the service needs to be started from a network drive. Is there any service account that *can* access network drives or a way around this? thanks again

Comment: You will probably need to talk to your sysadmin. However, your can always run a service using your own interactive log on account. Provided that the admin has not denied your account "log on as service" rights. That would be the first thing I would try. Configure the log on user in the service control panel whilst debugging. No need to write code here.